# wht do this mean "0123456789abcdef"[num % base]

Tags: c

```
"0123456789abcdef"[num % base]
```

Putting `num%base = 0`

```
"0123456789abcdef"[0]
```

It gives 48 but how.
When i use 0 as index than it should give me 0.

Comment: The ASCII code for `'0'` is 48.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"0123456789abcdef"` is a string literal, which defines an array filled with those characters (plus a terminating null character). `[num % base]` is a subscript operator with the subscript `num % base`.

So `"0123456789abcdef"[num % base]` selects one of the characters from the array. It is intended to select the character for the last digit of `num` when it is represented as a numeral in base `base`.

When `num % base` is zero, it selects the “0” character. Your C implementation uses ASCII codes for some characters. The ASCII code for “0” is 48.